# How to style MaterialButton for dark and light mode?

Tags: android

I have a `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` with two `MaterialButton` in it. I am trying to implement light and dark theme.

For light theme, it looks like this:

[image]

And for dark theme:

[image]

I can get the dark theme work perfectly with this code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:checkedButton="@id/languageGerman"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    app:singleSelection="true">
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/languageGerman"
        style="@style/Widget.App.SwitchButton"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimarySurface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:letterSpacing="0"
        android:text="@string/language_de" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/languageEnglish"
        style="@style/Widget.App.SwitchButton"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimarySurface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:letterSpacing="0"
        android:text="@string/language_en" />
```

But using this code, the light theme looks weird:

[image]

Here, it seems that the color for the selected button is not maintained. I have tried out many combinations of `backgroundTint` and `background`, but I can't get it to work. How can I achieve a behaviour like the first two pictures above? Thanks!